# What is the prefered solution for corrupted namenode metadata

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hdp, namenode

we have HDP cluster , version `2.6.5`

cluster include management of two name-node ( one is active and the secondary is standby )

and 65 datanode machines

we have problem with the standby name-node that not started and from the namenode logs we can see the following

```
2021-01-01 15:19:43,269 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1783)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 90247527115, but got txid 90247903412.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.MetaRecoveryContext.editLogLoaderPrompt(MetaRecoveryContext.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadFSEdits(FSEditLogLoader.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:693)
```

from ambari we can see that standby is down

[image]

for now the active namenode is up but the standby name node is down , and the root cause for this issue is because  **namenode matadata is damaged/corrupted.**

so we have two solution - **A** or **B**

A)

run the following recover on standby namenode

```
su
hadoop namenode -recover
```

B)

Put Active NN in safemode

```
su hdfs 
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
```

Do a savenamespace operation on Active NN

```
su hdfs 
hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace
```

Leave Safemode

```
 su hdfs 
 hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Login to Standby NN

Run below command on Standby namenode to get latest fsimage that we saved in above steps.

```
 su  hdfs 
 hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby -force
```

**what is the preferred solution for our problem?**